# Why does java.sql.Date.getTime() returns 82_800_000 for 1970-01-02 instead of 86_400_000?

Tags: java, time, epoch

One day has 86400 seconds. Many time objects are related to the Epoch on 1970-01-01. The API says

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT

The following code returns 82800000. Why? What is wrong?

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( "1970-01-02" );
long millis = sqlDate.getTime();
System.out.println( "expected=" + 86400000 + " " + sqlDate
            + "\n  result=" + millis );
```

Comment: What's your timezone? My guessing is GMT -1

Answer (score 2):

> A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have
>   passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT

So if your time zone is GMT+1, you will get 82800000 for January 2, 1970:

`(January 1, 1970 + one day - one hour)`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that a date includes the timezone ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're living in Germany, your timezone is `CET` (or `GMT+1`)

You're parsing the date corresponding to your own timezone so there'll be a difference of one hour between the value you're parsing and the initial beginning.

That said, the instant is the same.